# Need help with simple angularjs programming

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do simple programming in angularjs. I have created two buttons. The first button has text "clickHere", and the second has no text. My task is when I click the button that has text, it will automatically get empty and the second button will have the same text. (and vice versa).

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.name1 = '';
    var val = 'Hello';
    $scope.click0 = function() {
        //alert("hello!");
        $scope.name = $scope.name1;
        $scope.name1="";
        //return val;
    };
    $scope.click1 = function() {
        //alert("hello!");
        $scope.name1 = $scope.name;
        $scope.name="";
//        return val;
    };
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="click0()" >{{name}}</button>
    <button ng-click="click1()" >{{name1}}</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/simpleorchid/a65zV/

Comment: What doesn't work? I've tried the fiddle and don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue was you were overwriting your stored value. I added a `$scope` variable called `word`, and now it works:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.word = 'Superhero';
    $scope.name = $scope.word;
    $scope.name1 = '';

    $scope.click0 = function() {
        $scope.name1 = $scope.word;
        $scope.name="";
    };
    $scope.click1 = function() {
        $scope.name = $scope.word;
        $scope.name1="";
    };

}
```

#### [Udpated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pWjLR/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/pWjLR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `click1()` with `click0()` like in the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a65zV/9/) and everything will work just as you want it to.